# How to remove only trailing spaces of a string in Java and keep leading spaces?

Tags: java, android, string, trim

The [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) function removes both the trailing and leading space, however, if I only want to remove the trailing space of a string, how can I do it?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

## Since JDK 11

If you are on JDK 11 or higher you should probably be using [stripTrailing()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripTrailing()).

---

## Earlier JDK versions

Using the regular expression `\s++$`, you can replace all trailing space characters (includes space and tab characters) with the empty string (`""`).

```
final String text = "  foo   ";
System.out.println(text.replaceFirst("\\s++$", ""));
```

**Output**

```
  foo
```

[Online demo.](https://ideone.com/x6kJ8P)

Here's a breakdown of the regex:

- `\s` – any whitespace character,
- `++` – match one or more of the previous token (possessively); i.e., match one or more whitespace character. The `+` pattern is used in its [possessive form](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `++`, which takes less time to detect the case when the pattern does not match.
- `$` – the end of the string.

Thus, the regular expression will match as much whitespace as it can that is followed directly by the end of the string: in other words, the trailing whitespace.

The investment into learning regular expressions will become more valuable, if you need to extend your requirements later on.

**References**

- [Java regular expression syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: @WChargin Thank you for providing the breakdown of the regular expression. I think more people should follow your lead and improve answers.

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to use Apache Commons `StringUtils`, specifically [StringUtils.stripEnd](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#stripEnd%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
String stripped = StringUtils.stripEnd("   my lousy string    "," ");
```

Comment: sorry, i'm on android, so i could not use it

Comment: I agree. However, you should make it a point to tag your questions with `android` as `android` is not `Java`.

Comment: @TimBender This is my fault, I removed the android tag, since the question seemed generic Java to me. I am sorry.

Comment: Android can use this with no doubt. You should import org.apache.commons.lang3 not org.apache.commons.lang.
It works on API 19+.

Answer (score 11):

I modified the original `java.lang.String.trim()` method a bit and it should work:

```
  public String trim(String str) {
        int len = str.length();
        int st = 0;

        char[] val = str.toCharArray();

        while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
            len--;
        }
        return str.substring(st, len);
    }
```

Test:

```
  Test test = new Test();
  String sample = "            Hello World               "; // A String with trailing and leading spaces
  System.out.println(test.trim(sample) + " // No trailing spaces left");
```

Output:

```
        Hello World // No trailing spaces left
```

Answer (score 7):

As of `JDK11` you can use [stripTrailing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripTrailing()):

```
String result = str.stripTrailing();
```

Answer (score 4):

The most practical answer is @Micha's, <strike>Ahmad's is reverse of what you wanted so</strike> but here's what I came up with in case you'd prefer not to use unfamiliar tools or to see a concrete approach.

```
public String trimEnd( String myString ) {

    for ( int i = myString.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {
        if ( myString.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
            continue;
        } else {
            myString = myString.substring( 0, ( i + 1 ) );
            break;
        }
    }
    return myString;
}
```

Used like:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    String s = "    Some text here   ";
    System.out.println( s + "|" );
    s = trimEnd( s );
    System.out.println( s + "|" );
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Some text here   |
> Some text here|
> ```

Comment: "not allowed to use regex" ... why?

Comment: @WChargin: Student. We are allowed to use C++, C#, and/or Java, but no utilities or anything that makes your life easy. I'm going to update it to be more general.

Answer (score 3):

The best way in my opinion:

```
public static String trimEnd(String source) {
    int pos = source.length() - 1;
    while ((pos >= 0) && Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(pos))) {
        pos--;
    }
    pos++;
    return (pos < source.length()) ? source.substring(0, pos) : source;
}
```

This does not allocate any temporary object to do the job and is faster than using a regular expression. Also it removes all whitespaces, not just ' '.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very short, efficient and easy-to-read version:

```
public static String trimTrailing(String str) {
    if (str != null) {
        for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                return str.substring(0, i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

As an alternative to `str.charAt(i) != ' '` you can also use `!Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)` if you want to use a broader definition of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Spring framework gives a useful org.springframework.util.StringUtils.

[trimTrailingWhitespace](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#trimTrailingWhitespace(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

This code is intended to be read a easily as possible by using descriptive names (and avoiding regular expressions).

It does use Java 8's `Optional` so is not appropriate for everyone.

```
public static String removeTrailingWhitspace(String string) {
    while (hasWhitespaceLastCharacter(string)) {
        string = removeLastCharacter(string);
    }
    return string;
}

private static boolean hasWhitespaceLastCharacter(String string) {
    return getLastCharacter(string)
            .map(Character::isWhitespace)
            .orElse(false);
}

private static Optional<Character> getLastCharacter(String string) {
    if (string.isEmpty()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(string.charAt(string.length() - 1));
}

private static String removeLastCharacter(String string) {
    if (string.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String must not be empty");
    }
    return string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

String value= "Welcome to java  ";

So we can use

value = value.trim();

Comment: The OP asks to only remove trailing spaces.

Comment: trim() Returns a copy of the string, with both leading and trailing whitespace omitted.