# How to check for initial spaces in the text entered in edit text android

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I have an issue in validating edit text in my android application. I have tried many methods and none of them are suiting my scenario. When user tries to save the post the entering only spaces in edit text field I need to pop out an error message. But I am able to check the condition where user enters only spaces.

I have used the following methods:

```
if(subjectText.isEmpty() || detailsText.isEmpty() || subjectText.equals(" ") || detailsText.equals(" ")){

// perform operation.

}
```

Here the `.equals(" ")` method checks only for one space. If the user entry is some thing like `"            "` and not text, how can I check tell the user there is not text. Please any one let me know. All suggestions are welcome.

I have also tried with `.contains(" ")` method, this method solves the problem but even if there is space in between text it pops the error which should not happen. If the user entry is `"how are you"`, the `.contains(" ")` method give an error.

How can I solve this issue. Please help me come out of this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `startsWith(" ")` to detect whitespace at the beginning of a string.

**Edit :**

maybe like this

```
if(subjectText.isEmpty() || detailsText.isEmpty() || subjectText.startsWith(" ") || detailsText.startsWith(" ")){

// perform operation.

}
```

Comment: Will this work even if there are more than one space characters at the start?

Comment: It works because it will check for a whitespace at the start. if there are more than one whitespace, the first whitespace will make the condition returns true.

Answer (score 0):

try this, to remove all the whitespace that you have entered from the EditText

```
if(subjectText.trim().length()<1){
   //perform action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a regex check for that. Like this that checks for whitespaces;

```
if(... || subjectText.matches("^\\s*$") || ... }
```

For white space you can also do

```
subjectText.trim().lenght==0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final String subjectText = "  foo   ";
if (subjectText.replaceFirst("\\s+$", "").length() == 0) {

// perform operation.

}
```

Code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974267/how-to-remove-only-trailing-spaces-of-a-string-in-java-and-keep-leading-spaces)