# Concat multiple String getters

Tags: java, spring-boot

Currently I'm trying to concat multiple String getters from a DTO.

For example I have created a getter for the `FullStreetName` (This includes Street name, house number and if exists the house number extension)

```java
public String getFullStreetName() {
    return getStreetName() + " " + getHousenumber() + " " + getHouseNumberExtension();
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the `FullStreetName` has a weird space at the end if `GetHouseNumberExtension` is `null`

[image]

What's the best approach to concat multiple strings if one value can be possible `null`?

Comment: In your case it may be easier to strip the trailing space(s) instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974267/how-to-remove-only-trailing-spaces-of-a-string-in-java-and-keep-leading-spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the individual components into a stream, filter them, and ultimately join them into a string:

```java
public String getFullStreetName() {
  return Stream.of(getStreetName(), getHousenumber(), getHouseNumberExtension())
      .filter(str -> str != null && !str.isEmpty())
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringBuilder` and append if the variable isn't null, Suppose getHouseNumberExtension() can be null, So You can rewrite it by bellow code:

```
public String getFullStreetName() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(getStreetName() + " " + getHousenumber());
    return getHouseNumberExtension() == null ? result.toString() : result.append(" ").append(getHouseNumberExtension()).toString();
}
```

Soppose getHouseNumberExtension() can be null or empty string, To validate more cleanly use `commons-lang3`. to import it in the gradle project add `implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:version")` and rewrite it to bellow code.

```
public String getFullStreetName() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(getStreetName() + " " + getHousenumber());
    return StringUtils.isNoneBlank(getHouseNumberExtension()) 
           ? result.toString() 
           : result.append(" ").append(getHouseNumberExtension()).toString();
}
```